# AJAX XMLHttpRequest 'bouncing back' when sending vars to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I apologize if I don't articulate my problem correctly, but I'll give it my best shot. I've been looking all over the net for info which can help me with this issue, to no avail.
Just a bit of background. I'm an experienced web coder, though haven't done webwork in a few years prior to this, I have done a fair bit of work in PHP and javascript before and these days I work with C++, so I'm fairly experienced with programming principles.

I'm building some blog software, and inb4wordpress and jQuery, I simply don't care. So spare it please... I'm loading some blog entries into an element through a simple AJAX request function. This function is detailed below: ( It's been changed to a 3 function example I found on the net while I was trying to debug this issue, no one's 'simple' code seems to work. )

The problem is detailed beneath the code.

```
var httpObject = null;

function getHTTPObject(){
    if(window.ActiveXObject) return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else if(window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest();
    else {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
        return null;
    }
}

function setOutput(){
    if(httpObject.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById("entries").innerHTML = httpObject.responseText;
    }
}

function loadEntries(s) {
    httpObject = getHTTPObject();
    if (httpObject != null) {
        httpObject.open("GET","entries.php?" + s,true);
        httpObject.send(null);
        httpObject.onreadystatechange = setOutput;
    }
}
```

Simple stuff? I can't seem to see any errors there. This is how the function is called:

```
        <div id='entries'>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            loadEntries('blog=<?php echo $process['id']; ?>&page=0');
        </script>
    </div>
```

also simple.
Here's the PHP code for 'entries.php':

```
<?php
    require_once('inc/bloginc.php');

    if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $page = intval($_GET['page']);
    } else $page = 0;

    $entries = 3;
    $init = $page * $entries;
    $limit = $entries + $init;

    if(!isset($_GET['blog'])) die("WTF DIE");
    else $blog = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['blog']);

    $tag = '';
    if(isset($_GET['tag'])) {
        $tag = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['tag']);
        echo "<span class='blogEntryBody'>viewing entries tagged with: '" . $tag . "' / <a href='' onclick=\"";
        echo "loadEntries('blog=" . $blog . "')";
        echo "\">clear?</a></span></br>";
        echo "<hr>";
    }

    $numposts = nResults($blog, $tag);
    buildEntries(getEntries($blog, $tag, $init, $limit));

    if($numposts > $entries) {
        echo "</br><span class='blogEntryBody'>";
        if($page > 0) {
            echo "<a href='' onClick=\"";
            echo "loadEntries('blog=" . $blog;
            if(isset($_GET['tag'])) echo "&tag=" . $tag;
            echo "&page=" . (--$page) . "')";
            echo "\">Previous Entries</a>";
            echo " / ";
        }

        echo "<a href='' onClick=\"";
        echo "loadEntries('blog=" . $blog;
        if(isset($_GET['tag'])) echo "&tag=" . $tag;
        echo "&page=" . (++$page) . "')";
        echo "\">Next Entries</a>";

        echo "<br></span>";
    }

?>
```

okay, now here's where things get tricky:

When sending vars to 'entries.php', such as: entries.php?blog=walk&page=1

They intermittently work, some of these work, but some don't.

I know it's not the PHP code, since loading entries.php up in a new window and manually passing these vars elicits the desired results. What happens is that the HTTP GET request returns 'undefined' in Firefox webdev console, such as this:

> [14:47:33.505] GET http://localhost/meg/entries.php?blog=walk&tag=lorem [undefined 2ms]

^ The 'tag' variable usually works, it's normally the 'page' variable that sends everything haywire.

What happens is, after clicking 'next page', you quickly see a blank div, and then it quickly bounces back to the previous state. You see all this loading in the console. It'll return 'undefined' then reload the previous state. Which is just puzzling.

I don't understand why this would be occurring.

I hope I've provided enough information, and set it out in an easy to understand format. I'm new to asking questions. I usually just 'googleit' or RTM. But I think maybe this time someone else will have seen this before.

Oh, and I've tested in chrome, same issue. I'm really puzzled, but open to the possibility that maybe I've overlooked something small and crucial.

Thanks!

Comment: Define "don't work". Is your `setOutput` being called? Does it throw an error inside? Note the callback errors are swallowed by the browser, so you have to do `try/catch` inside. Is `innerHTML` not being set?

Comment: You seem a little jaded in your question. If you can boil the problem down to a specific concern and highlight that (with evidence), this is really all that matters.

Comment: Also, in the past few years, jQuery and other libraries have abstracted most of the AJAX experience, so it's not so difficult. Especially if you're an experienced coder, look into using jQuery for AJAX at least.

Comment: @liho: Yep, setOutput is being called. innerHTML is being set, This NORMALLY works, just in certain cases it fails. When passing certain variables.
I might try using try/catch blocks.
I'm a little confused by what you mean about 'jaded'? did you read my question?

Comment: so what doesn't work then? And I agree with Jared. Your question is all over the place. You throw a pile of code asking us to find a problem in it. You need to debug yourself and narrow the issue down. Nobody gonna just look at it and tell you what it is.

Comment: Ok, "guarded". When I read your question, I didn't get the feeling you trusted how others might interpret your question.

Comment: Did you read my post? I know how to debug it, and I've been doing that. The problem is BELOW THE CODE. I'm not looking for someone to 'debug my code'. I'm having an issue with the HTTP GET request failing when sending certain vars through the AJAX function, I was wondering if there was something simple I may have overlooked, and if I didn't post my code, what good would asking be?

Comment: oh, and just to satisfy the jQuery response. I tried doing this same thing through jQuery and had the same issue, which is even more puzzling. I don't really like jQuery much, but I was willing to test it out. Experienced the same problem.
I'm testing all this through XAMPP, which I just thought I'd mention, even though it's kinda obvious.

Comment: When I say debug I don't mean trying different browsers. I mean throwing `alert(httpObject.responseText)` inside that callback and seeing what it produces.

Comment: already way ahead of you. Tried that, in most cases it shows exactly what it should, but when it fails. I get this curious 'instant popup' which shows nothing, is canceled by the browser, and then it bounces back to what it had before. I get this strange error in the browser debug console:

[15:06:55.777] uncaught exception: [Exception... "prompt aborted by user"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource:///components/nsPrompter.js :: openTabPrompt :: line 462"  data: no]

the XMLhttprequest response code is 0 on these errors

Comment: so anyone have any -helpful- answers?

Answer (score 0):

Well it happens few times that ajax doesn't works in chrome & explorer so my suggestion to use jquery because in jquery they already include codes for explorer and chrome.

you can use
`$.get , $.post or $.ajax` methods easily.